# Changing Viridis to different color palette

Tags: r, choropleth, color-palette, r-mapview, viridis

How can one change this viridis color platte as shown below to other types of viridis color palette??The code used and the map displayed below is shown for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `col.regions` option does that.  You can give it a different color palette as an argument:

```r
library(mapview)
data(franconia)
mapview(franconia, 
        zcol = "district",  
        col.region=colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asked specifically about the viridis color palette, code would be :

```r
library(mapview)
data(franconia)
mapview(franconia, 
        zcol = "district",  
        col.region=viridis::viridis_pal(option = "A"))
```

Where you can change `option="A"` for "B" or "C" (the current palette used is "D").
For using the other gradients from viridis, you can use

```r
library(mapview)
data(franconia)
mapview(franconia, 
        zcol = "district",  
        col.region=viridis::mako(n = 3))
```

where n must be at least as big as the number of discrete variable or bins.
For your gradient, I see you have 6 values on your scale, so I'd put n at 6.